# How to draw a schematic diagram for rectangular loops of wires

Tags: schematics, diagram

In my electrical system, there are multiple rectangular loops of wires. Each of these loops is made up of four individual wire segments that are interconnected using right angle connectors to form a rectangular shape. Every consecutive loop in this series is separated by a resistor, which effectively creates a voltage divider network. This results in a stepped-up voltage across each successive wire loop.

I'm trying to get all this down in a schematic diagram, but I'm not totally sure I'm doing it right. Could anyone guide me on how to correctly draw these wire loops in a schematic diagram? I've put what I have so far below. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What are the loops for? Is this like an electric field thing? Some physics apparatus?

Comment: Your guess is correct! This is only a part of the setup but overall the purpose is to create an electric field inside of the rectangular box's volume.

Comment: are the loops in series with the resistors? ... your diagram shows only one connection to each loop ... should there be two connections to each loop?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a box with field plates in it.  Something like this:

[image: Diagram]

Plates as flat lines are traditional vacuum tube symbology.  Or "-<" shapes, usually for photomultiplier dynodes and CRT deflection plates (which are kind of, well, bent!).

Maybe the box is further made suggestive of what it is (some kind of chamber or whatever?), maybe the plates instead of being flat "field plates", you use a more rhombic outline shape suggestive of flat squares in 3D (which is also fine for a wire frame outline of course); etc.  Nothing so strong as to suggest mechanical dimensions, but enough to suggest the relative arrangement of identifiable things.

Note that a ground reference has to be placed somewhere.  I've drawn possible top or bottom connections, or maybe it's a ground/earth symbol and that's enough, maybe it's another electrode, or another part of the system shown on the same schematic...  Some kind of reference is required.